# Laravel: connect to digital ocean server with ssh and upload files to it

Tags: laravel, ssh, digital-ocean

I'm new to using forge, and i was wondering how i can connect to one of my servers (SFTP + SSH) in laravel 5.

My endgoal is to upload files to another server using Laravel.

What i have so far:

```
    Config::set('remote.connections.tenant.server', 'ip adress server');
    Config::set('remote.connections.tenant.port', '22');
    Config::set('remote.connections.tenant.host', 'example.com');
    Config::set('remote.connections.tenant.user', 'username provided in the mail from forge');
    Config::set('remote.connections.tenant.pass', 'password provided in the mail from forge');
    Config::set('remote.connections.tenant.key', 'path to the key stored inside my application');

    SSH::into('tenant')->put($localFile, $remotePath);
```

"Example.com is just a demonstration name"

I get this error:

> Cannot connect to :22. Error 110. Connection timed out

Am I going in the right direction, or is this completely wrong? Help would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: How is your firewall config? Timeout can be a closed port.

Comment: @JonatasWalker it allows port 22 when i do ufw status

Comment: Can you make a simple ssh connection from terminal?

Comment: @JonatasWalker Yes thats posible

Comment: I would suggest you create a tunnel between the servers ... if this is your case I can show some code I use here. Here is a [link](http://www.brandonchecketts.com/archives/creating-a-permanent-ssh-tunnel-between-linux-servers)

Comment: Why are you using both a password and a ssh key?